# Jquery problem: trying to stop an animation after first click

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

Jquery newbie here =) so I've got a code that slides the menu divs to the right, the problem is that I don't want the menu to keep doing the animation after the first click on any of those divs. I've tried return false but it didn't help. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#menu_home").click(function(){
    $("#menu_home").animate({"left": "+=419px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_portfolio").animate({"left": "+=313px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_us").animate({"left": "+=210px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_blog").animate({"left": "+=104px"}, "slow");

  });

  $("#menu_portfolio").click(function(){
    $("#menu_home").animate({"left": "+=419px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_portfolio").animate({"left": "+=313px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_us").animate({"left": "+=210px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_blog").animate({"left": "+=104px"}, "slow");
  });

  $("#menu_us").click(function(){
    $("#menu_home").animate({"left": "+=419px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_portfolio").animate({"left": "+=313px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_us").animate({"left": "+=210px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_blog").animate({"left": "+=104px"}, "slow");
  });

  $("#menu_blog").click(function(){
    $("#menu_home").animate({"left": "+=419px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_portfolio").animate({"left": "+=313px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_us").animate({"left": "+=210px"}, "slow");
      $("#menu_blog").animate({"left": "+=104px"}, "slow");
  });

});
```

Comment: You may want to cache the selectors that you are repeating. For example:
var menu_home = $("#menu_home");
Then you can access them like so: 
menu_home.animate({"left": "+=419px"}, "slow");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with jQuery's [one()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one) event.  It will only fire once.

```
 // bind event to each matched element
 $("#menu_home, #menu_portfolio, #menu_us, #menu_blog").one('click', function(){
    $("#menu_home").animate({"left": "+=419px"}, "slow");
    $("#menu_portfolio").animate({"left": "+=313px"}, "slow");
    $("#menu_us").animate({"left": "+=210px"}, "slow");
    $("#menu_blog").animate({"left": "+=104px"}, "slow");
    // unbind event so remainder of elements wont fire event
    $("#menu_home, #menu_portfolio, #menu_us, #menu_blog").unbind('click');
 });
```

Comment: Since you `unbind()`, there's no difference between doing this with `one()` vs `click()`.

Comment: I figured it'd be worth mentioning the function.  I also didn't initially notice that each animation was exactly the same.  The unbind was a late addition to fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unbind click event from elements. You probably want

```
$("#menu_home, #menu_portfolio, #menu_us, #menu_blog").unbind('click');
```

at the end of every method.